# While unzipping, ZipEntry returns foldername/filename instead of only fodername/ , and these throws File Not Found Exception

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, unzip, php-ziparchive

I'm creating zip from back-end using PHP. and I want to unzip at Android side.

***My Folder structure of Zip includes***

> - Folder 1
>
>   - file
>   - file
> - Folder 2
>
>   - file
>   - file
> - File

To create zip I use following code

```
foreach ($files as $name => $file)
                    {
                        // echo $file.'  --   ';
                        if (!$file->isDir())
                        {
                            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
                            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);
                            //echo dirname($file);
                            $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);

                        }
                    }
```

In android I use following code to unzip

```
        InputStream is;
        ZipInputStream zis;
        try {
            String filename;
            is = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
            ZipEntry ze;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int count;
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                filename = ze.getName();
                // it will show 
                // it will generate an Exception...
                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    File fmd = new File(location + filename);
                    fmd.mkdirs();
                    continue;
                }
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(location + filename);
                while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                fout.close();
                zis.closeEntry();
            }
            zis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it's not getting me proper output which I needs.

I expect output at

> **ze.getName()** is **FolderName/**

but I the actual output is

> **FolderName/filename**

so it do not consider forward slash as directory and it throws File Not Found Exception.

Comment: ```if (!$file->isDir())``` combined with ```$file->getRealPath();``` would result a full path to a file not a directory

Comment: use ```$file->getPath()``` instead to get the path without file name

Comment: @Talal It's not working with the `$file->getPath()`

Comment: ZipArchive doesnt accept adding folders only files or create empty folder. i'm only commenting on the php side if you add a file lets say ```$zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);``` where ```$relativePath``` is ```somedir/anotherdir/somefile.txt``` the ```somedir/anotherdir/``` will be created automatically

Comment: Your comment for PHP side is working well, that I have already done using `$zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);`, But Android side, I got ZipEntry directly like `somedir/somefile.txt` as a file so it will not first create directory, it directly finds the file inside directory. So there might be possible from PHP side it will always add a file instead of directory.

Comment: i don't think there is a php side to your problem. if the output zip file is correct as expected after php and before Android stuff. good luck with that i'm out :)